# FBAudienceNetwork SDK 4.22.0 load native ad no fill

Tags: ios, facebook

[When I upgrade SDK to the version of 4.22.0,I use the following method to load the native ad, but i always get the error code 1001(no fill).
the SDK version 4.22.0 or less , There is no such problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbuXV.jpg)